# Authentication cookie with subdomains

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

i have an asp.net website `http://www.site.com`. This web app is also running on `http://subdomain1.site.com` and `http://subdomain2.site.com`. Now i want to set authentication cookie in such a way that `http://site.com`and `http://www.site.com`share authentication cookie but it should not be shared by `http://subdomain1.site.com`. similarly, `http://www.domain1.site.com` and `http://domain1.site.com` should share cookie but it should not be shared by `http://domain2.site.com` or `http://www.domain2.site.com`. How can i handle this with asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using different cookie names on different domains as described in [this article](http://davestechshop.net/FormsAuthCookiesAndSubdomainNames2)

Answer (score 1):

By default, cookies are associated with a specific domain. For example, if your site is www.contoso.com, the cookies you write are sent to the server when users request any page from that site. (This might not include cookies with a specific path value.) If your site has subdomains—for example, contoso.com, sales.contoso.com, and support.contoso.com—then you can associate cookies with a specific subdomain.

```
Response.Cookies["domain"].Domain = "support.contoso.com";
```

Normally a cookie set on contoso.com will be accessed by all subdomain. but if you want to limit sub domain for the cookie you should manually set domain property for each domain you want them to access.

Regards.

Comment: thnx shoaib, i will try this one out. should port be part of domain?

Comment: I do not see any port property in `HttpCookie`object

Comment: oops sorry port is actually not available for web.httpcookie.. but port should be part of the domain.. http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/#3.2

Comment: shoaib thanx a lot for the follow up